# How to implement the mentioned regex in the Python Code

Tags: python, regex

I have a regex `PROTO\s*\{(\n*\s*\w+,)+\n*\s*\}` to match the text file which is like below

```
PROTO {
    product1,
    product2,
    product3,
    product4,
    product5,
    product6,
}

SAVE_LOG: True

SUMMARY: True
```

How can I use the above mentioned regex to the output in a List like

`['product1', 'product2', 'product3', 'product4', 'product5', 'product6']`

Comment: Does it have to be regex specifically? Why not string manipulation?

Comment: The product name and number can be different. And the formatting too..specially the position of the braces and the SPACE between PROTO and `{`..string manipulation hence can be difficult..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get the array you want:

```
import itertools
protos = re.findall(r'PROTO\s*\{(.*?)\}', data, flags=re.DOTALL)
lines = [re.findall(r'(\w+),', x) for x in protos]
products = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(lines))
```

Comment: What is the purpose of non-greedy search here..You can achieve the same result with out the `?`

Comment: If there is another block later in the file (which would have a trailing `}`) then you don't want to match all the way to that. The non-greedy match is trying to make sure you get only what's in the `PROTO` block.

Comment: If you're guaranteed to never ever have another `}` after the `PROTO` block, then yes, it's the same thing with or without the `?`.

Comment: Thanks for the info..Yes I am guaranteed not to have another block further down..

Comment: Moreover what is the purpose of `itertools`..I can just simply do `[re.findall(r'(\w+),', x) for x in protos][0]` to get the list

Comment: Yep...I had accidentally started using the sample text from a now-deleted answer that included additional `PROTO` blocks, so `protos` was actually a list-of-lists. `itertools....` was just used to flatten that down to a 1-dimensional list.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't need regex, you can probably achieve what you want with simple string functions.

```
with open('path/to/file.txt','r') as fp:
    product_list = []
    for line in fp.readlines():
        if line.strip()[:5] == 'PROTO':
            append_bool = True
        elif append_bool and line.find('}')>=0:
            append_bool = False
        if append_bool:
            product_list.append(line.strip().replace(',',''))
```

Comment: Thanks but can you the regex too please??

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to install the newer [`regex`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) module (which supports the `\G` modifier), you could come up with sth. like ([demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/rY2xQ6/1)):

```
(?:^PROTO\s*\{\s+|(?!\A)\G\s*)([^,\n\r]+),
```

In `Python` this would be:

```
import regex as re

string = """
PROTO {
    product1,
    product2,
    product3,
    product4,
    product5,
    product6,
}

SAVE_LOG: True

SUMMARY: True
"""

rx = re.compile(r"""
        (?:^PROTO\s*\{\s+   # look for PROTO at the beginning of the line,
                            # followed by whitespace and {
            |               # OR
            (?!\A)\G\s*)    # start at the previous match (make sure it's not the start)
        ([^,\n\r]+),        # look for sth. that is not a comma or newline
        """, re.VERBOSE|re.MULTILINE)

matches = rx.findall(string)
print matches
# ['product1', 'product2', 'product3', 'product4', 'product5', 'product6']
```

This has the advantage of only **one** regex (which is compiled, additionally), thus it is likely to be faster.

Comment: This was fascinating but it doesn't work if the formatting of the file changes

Comment: @MayukhSarkar: And *how* does the formatting change? Regular expressions are almost always bound to a specific format.

Comment: No...check @user2926055 answer...The formatting change means the newlines between `{` and the first entry..or the indentation before each proto names..

Comment: The idea is to get all the protos which are separated by `,` and enclosed within a tag `PROTO` with `{`

Comment: The regex in my main question keep on matching even if you change the formatting.

Comment: @MayukhSarkar: Just omit the `^` then (this binds the expression to the beginning of the line).